# WiFi Direct Connectivity as a service

Tags: android, android-service, wifi-direct, wifimanager, wifip2p

I am doing an android project. I am using wifi direct to establish communication between two modules. My doubt is that while using the wifi direct to connect to another device a dialog prompts whether to connect to that device. I want to avoid that prompt, It should be connected as it identifies a wifi module. that is by my understanding it should work as a background service. I am a beginner in android programming please help me out in solving this.

Thank You
Midhun

Comment: As far as I know, because of security thefts , its not possible to connect devices directly/without permission.

Comment: were you able resolve this issue ?